# Why Python built-in libraries does not follow naming convention?

Tags: python, pep8

This error is present on some of the main Python built-in libraries. For example:

```
"foo".startswith("bar") # instead of .starts_with
re.findall("[ab]", "foobar"]) # instead of .find_all
```

Is this just a compatibility issue? [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) states that method names must be written in lowercase with words separated by underscores.

Comment: Briefly: mistakes were made.

Comment: Note the second section of that document: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds

Comment: You're missing the clause of that "lowercase with underscores" note, specifying "as necessary to improve readability." "*as* necessary" doesn't mean "necessary all the time", it means "*when* necessary". That is, if the name is readable without the underscores, they aren't required. If the name is hard to read or too long, you use the underscores to break it up for readability, but for short names that are easy to parse, the underscores aren't needed.

Comment: For the record, I don't feel this is a duplicate of the other question. They're both about inconsistencies in the Python naming conventions, but it's a completely different inconsistency.

Comment: Backwards compatibility with things that was added to python before pep8 existed. PEP 8 was written in 2001, about ten years after the first version of python.

Comment: adding to the question class name examples - dataclasses.dataclass , collections.namedtuple .